# How to solve "ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor" error?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, listener, visual-studio

I am trying to create connection with the database for debugging ASP.Net website. Database is 11g Oracle DB... There is no problem when I connect using SQL Developer, however using Visual Studio I get the error of ORA-12514 (TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor). 11g ODAC for Visual Studio 2010 has been configured as well.  There are similar questions about this error, I could not find solution for my problem.

Thanks in advance for the help!!!

Comment: What version of Windows are you running?  Have you configured the TNS listener?  Have you invoked the `tnsping dbsid` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not have any clear explanation for this problem solution. However I used SID instead of service name in connection string and it worked.

**Edit:** A service name is more flexible than a SID would be. A database can dynamically register with a listener using one or more service names. In fact, more than one database can register with a listener using the same service name.A database on the other hand has a single SID. And a single SID goes to a single database. So I would say it is safe to use SID rather than service name.

Answer (score 0):

stop fsc service and restart all oracle services

Comment: This might answer the question (I'm not sure) but it's a bit on the brief side. You're more likely to attract up-votes if you edit your answer to explain what the underlying problem is, and how your solution will address that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Database Configuration Assistant > Configure Database > Choose Database > Configure.

After configuring close the Configuration Assistant then try to connect to SQL*Plus again.